# C# foreach leads to There is already an open DataReader associated error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider

I have the following bits of code in my accountRepository

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string email)
{
    // User rolesUser = FindByMail(email);
    IEnumerable<UserRole> RoleList = context.UserRolesSet.Where(u => u.user_id == 1).AsEnumerable();
    string[] arr1 = new string[RoleList.Count()];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (UserRole r in RoleList)
    {
        arr1[i] = r.roles.name;
        i++;
    }
    return arr1;
}
```

This should work but it doesn't. When it looping through the foreach loop it throws me this error:

> Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Is my foreach loop wrong?

Comment: Is the error happening on the first iteration of the loop? If it's on subsequent iterations, maybe the call to Roles is opening the DataReader.

Comment: You have to post the complete code. Then we were able to figure out the issue.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: This could be rewritten as `return context.UserRolesSet.Where(u => u.user_id == 1).Select(u => u.roles.name).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. Using ToArray makes sure it populates all of the UserRoles before hand so it'll be finished with the DataReader.

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string email)
{
    // User rolesUser = FindByMail(email);
    IEnumerable<UserRole> RoleList = context.UserRolesSet.Where(u => u.user_id == 1).ToArray();
    string[] arr1 = new string[RoleList.Count()];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (UserRole r in RoleList)
    {
        arr1[i] = r.roles.name;
        i++;
    }
    return arr1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the method:

```
IEnumerable<UserRole> RoleList = context.UserRolesSet.Where(u => u.user_id == 1);

return RoleList.Select(x => x.roles.name).ToArray();
```

Comment: Although why you would want to use one more than one line to accomplish this is a mystery to me.